# how apachetop can lose 90% of my traffic?

Tags: apache, parsing, logging

I have access.log with writes 3-4k lines per second in combined format.

When I run following command

```
tail -F /var/log/nginx/static16.log | pv -lr >/dev/null
```

I see [3.74k/s].

But when I run

```
apachetop -f /var/log/nginx/static16.log -d 10 -T 600
```

I see only 10% of my requests

```
All: 819 reqs ( 41.0/sec) 22.2M ( 1136.1K/sec)
```

Where is 90% of my requests?